# Error after installing Node 6, npm ERR! Invalid Version: 1.0.5beta

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using npm version 3.8.6.

I installed the latest Nodejs version, and did this

```
MacBook-Pro-de-MarceloRS:promo-mobile-ccsearchlp7a Marcelo$ rm -rf node_modules/; npm install
npm WARN deprecated gulp-foreach@0.1.0: Either use gulp-tap or gulp-flatmap, depending on your needs
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6

npm ERR! Invalid Version: 1.0.5beta
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Marcelo/Documents/Projects/BankOfAmericaApps/promo-mobile-ccsearchlp7a/npm-debug.log
MacBook-Pro-de-MarceloRS:promo-mobile-ccsearchlp7a Marcelo$ npm -v
3.8.6
```

Why do you think it is ?

I am using OSX El Capitan.

**EDIT**

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "promo-mobile-ccsearchlp7a",
  "app": "app",
  "dist": "dist",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "assemble": "~0.9.1",
    "browser-sync": "~2.11.1",
    "del": "~2.2.0",
    "engine-handlebars": "^0.8.0",
    "get-value": "~2.0.3",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.1.0",
    "gulp-cssnano": "~2.1.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-extname": "~0.2.2",
    "gulp-filter": "~3.0.1",
    "gulp-flatten": "~0.2.0",
    "gulp-foreach": "~0.1.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "~2.4.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~1.2.0",
    "gulp-notify": "~2.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "~2.2.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~1.5.2",
    "gulp-usemin": "~0.3.20",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.7",
    "handlebars-helpers": "github:assemble/handlebars-helpers#dev",
    "main-bower-files": "~2.9.0",
    "multimatch": "~2.1.0",
    "run-sequence": "~1.1.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.12.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "git-guppy": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp-watch": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a module you are trying to install listed in your package.json is trying to install a bad version 1.0.5beta. It's not a NPM problem but one of the installed modules. What is your package.json contents?

Comment: @BarryCarlyon see my **EDIT** part in the question

Comment: Lovely. Just trying a install locally here

Comment: I should also of asked for the npm-debug.log file as well that said *facepaw*

Comment: Probably need to take a look at the npm-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

Mine installed fine. But I note the following:

I installed under Node V5.

You are using Node V6.

I got the following notices:

```
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v6.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
```

You need to update you package.json to fetch lodash v4 and graceful-fs v4

(easiest method for me is to remove these two lines from package.json and `npm --save install package` install the two again